# access a dictionary key value inside a list

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary

Hi I have got a json response from al API with the following structure:

```
{'totalCount': 82,
'items': [{'id': '81',
           'priority': 3,
           'updatedAt': '2021-07-28T01:30:53.101Z',
           'status': {'value': None, 'source': None},
           'ps': {'value': None,'source': None},
           'lastUpdate': '2020-09-07T03:00:17.590Z'}
         ....
         ]}
```

So when I check the key, values with python:

```
for key, value in jsonResponse.items():
    print(key)
```

I am getting:

```
totalCount
items
```

Which are the keys of this dictionary.

So when I loop over the values, I get the ones inside the key called items, which at the same time is a list with dictionaries inside of it, how could I get the keys inside that list called items and the values inside of it as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to play with the `key, value`, and nest some `for` blocks:

```py
for key, value in jsonResponse.items():
    print(key)
    if key == "items":
        for items_key and items_value in value[0].items():
            # do whatever you want with the dictionary
            # items here?
```

That way, you can access to this specific dictionary.

Comment: If you feel fine with this answer, you may want to mark it as your selected answer. If not, you may want another opinion?